# is there a tool to see the difference between two database tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, diff

What is a good tool to see the differences between 2 tables (or even better, the datasets returned by 2 queries).

EDIT: I'm not interested in the schema changes. Just assume that the schemas are the same.

background as to why:
I'm porting some legacy code which can fill a database with some pre-calced data. The easiest way to see if I got everything right, is to check the output of the old program, with the new one. I was thinking that if there is some kind of 'diff' tool for databases, this might be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure a lot of people will point to the excellent tools of Red Gate, of which SQL Data Compare is the one that can compare data in tables. I'm using a simpler and cheaper alternative though: [SQLDBDiff](http://www.sqldbtools.com/Tools.aspx?ProductId=1). It can compare the data in two SQL server tables.

Comment: Great. Looks like just what I need!

Comment: I do have to say that the data compare option is really poor, in comparison to all the schema compare options in the tool. It just dumps the contents of the db to a textfile, and runs a freeware diff program on it.

Comment: Let us suggest Optillect Data Compare SQL - it has much more options than other tools.

Answer (score 3):

Nah.. Davert just bit faster than Red-Gate, the real new monster is **Optillect** with its [**Data Compare SQL**](http://optillect.com/products/datacomparesql/overview.html)
Just take a look at the performance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server_Compare_Tools#Performance

Answer (score 0):

Try [SQL Data Examiner](http://www.sqlaccessories.com/SQL_Data_Examiner/). This tool allows compare/synchronize not only tables, but also data returned by sql-queries.

Answer (score 0):

We would like to suggest you taking a look at our [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/). It is much faster (up to 3 times), comparing to competitors.